# Link-ing two WSO2 Identity Servers

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to configure in WSO2 Identity Server 4.5.0 as trusted identity provider for one tenant another WSO2 Identity Server?

The scenario for which I am asking this question is: A private cloud exposes some SAAS functionality to a number of tenants. Some of this will have the identity provided by the WSO2IS in the private cloud but for some it will have to be federated on the tenant premise where it will have to be integrated with something on their site.

AFAIK the whole Trusted Identity Provider functionality was designed to allow exactly this. Delegate the authentication functionality to some SAML 2.0 IDP in a remote deployment. I imagine this Trusted IDP can be any generic SAML 2.0 IPD so from this perspective it can be WSO2IS. Am I correct?

Is there any documentation, articles or samples (apart from the help of WSO2 which is very vague) that could help me in setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 IS can act as both IDP as well as SP.

So, in your scenario if you have one as IDP and the other IS will be the SP for first IDP in a federated scenario.

Is it possible to know more details on your question to understand the exactly what you meant by linking ?